# Java netbeans - how assign jtextfield value to zero if jtextfield value is empty

Tags: java, jtextfield

```
    double B=Double.parseDouble(emp_txt2.getText());
    double C=Double.parseDouble(nopay_txt3.getText());
    double E=Double.parseDouble(wop_txt4.getText());
    double F=Double.parseDouble(wop_txt5.getText());

   double f =B+C+E+F;
   String p = String.format("%.2f",f);
   lb1_total3.setText(p);
```

I want to assign double B,C,E,F values to zero when the jtextfield is empty.

Comment: Make use of a [Ternary Operator](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Java-Ternary-Operator-Examples), for example: `double B = Double.parseDouble((emp_txt2.getText().equals("") ? "0" : emp_txt2.getText()));`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this method instead of **Double.parseDouble**.

```
public static double tryParsDouble(String s, double defaultValue) {
     if (s == null) return defaultValue;

     try {
         return Double.parseDouble(s);
     } catch (NumberFormatException x) {
         return defaultValue;
     }  
}
```

And then to:

```
double F = tryParsDouble(wop_txt5.getText(), 0.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try entering the values in the `emp_text2` text field and the code returns the following values respectively: 
`""`, `"  "`, `"1"`, `"1.1"`, `"-1.1"`, `"1.0  "` returns `0.0`, `0.0`, `1.0`, `1.1`, `-1.1`, `1.0`.

What happens if the input is `"1.1x"` ? This throws `NumberFormatException` - and the application needs to figure what to do.

```
double value = getDoubleValue(emp_text2.getText());
...

private static double getDoubleValue(String input) {

    double result = 0d;

    if ((input == null) || input.trim().isEmpty()) {
        return result;
    }

    try {
        result = Double.parseDouble(input);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        // return result -or-
        // rethrow the exception -or-
        // whatever the application logic says
    }

    return result;
}
```